# Wireless printer only prints from web interface?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printing, printer, hp

I do tech support for a living and am stumped over this case.

Printer: HP officejet 5200.

Computer: Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2

As title says, it can print from the web interface **only**. You know, typing IP address in the browser. Can easily print network config pages and such from there.

Kept giving an error when I printed anywhere else, whether test pages or word documents. When I tried to do a test page from the printer's properties it said something like "parameters are incorrect".
Oh, and USB works perfectly. Just need to get the wifi going, this user has multiple printers.
Won't bother with more details yet until someone engages. Appreciate any help!

***Edit***- Great questions guys, thanks. 1) HP Smart does detect it, yes. Did not test print from the app because user has to make an account first. 2) Printer was added from control panel first and when we had the issue, then we did it through add printers and scanners in Settings. Same problem. 3) Checked port number and driver and they're fine. 4) Print driver is the basic one off the HP site for this model.Basic_Webpack_x64-44.9.2759-OJ5200_Basicx64_Webpack.exe
I had to extract the exe and install the infs though, and this worked with USB.
5) Direct HP was available and wanted to try it but he couldn't find his WPS PIN. But I selected the right kind after.
6) After our meeting I found a comment online saying adding "everyone" full permissions to the temp folder could resolve this. Makes some sense since I installed driver with admin rights, so maybe they are in my admin temp folder instead of the user's? Idk... 7) Notably the printer wifi component worked fine on his old work computer. 8) We did not try to reset it. 9) in all this the first thing I missed was restarting. Ugh..

Comment: 1)have you tried to reset printer in any way? 2)have you tried printing from more than one PC? 3)how did you add the printer? 4)do you know the print driver version you have installed?

Comment: Can the HP Smart application detect the printer?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment. I won’t be notified of a comment only an edit to your question

Comment: Does the printer appear as a "DirectHP..." rather than a networked printer? That will prevent "conventional" wireless printing.

Comment: Ok, edited the post. Also, I just figured out that you can print just fine from the web interface without even needing a driver installed! That explains a lot. So it must be the driver was installed incorrectly... will be meeting with the user again after the holiday.